# React Native warning: RCTC module not exported

Tags: react-native

I am getting a warning when running my React Native app on iOS:

> Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add more details plz. Did you add any native code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This occurs with RN 0.55.3 and probably any newer version.

For now it's not the best solution, but to avoid the warning we can ignore it:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Class RCTCxxModule']);
```

Comment: Add this in `App.js` file just after `import {...} from 'react-native';`

Answer (score 2):

Using this no need to import YellowBox. Without any dependency and declaration in header just put:

> console.disableYellowBox = true;

this line in the constructor.

```
 constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {           
       }
       console.disableYellowBox = true;
 }
```